# Automate command prompt with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I want to automate a command mode script using bat file.
For the first option, there are two sub-options,then giving one, one another option will come. 
Algorithm :

```
Enter your choice below:
Press 1 for fruit and 2 for meat: **//I want to press 1**
**After pressing 1**, 
Press 1 for apple and 2 for mango : **//I want to press 21**
```

Then the output will come as "I love mango".
The whole thing is already done by c++and its running fine.

I used in bat file:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    start fruit.exe
```

Then the first option is coming, and now I want to answer the rest and pass through them using bat file. Is it possible? I am very new to it.

Comment: As soon as you say start fruit.exe then your whole question becomes unclear.  It's unclear what fruit.exe does. And since it is unclear what fruit.exe does, it's then unclear what you want the bat file to do

Comment: I have not done it in a while but you can look up about the choice command.  And batch files don't have loop structures, you use goto to do any iteration, recursion(*cough*) or ending.

Comment: @barlop Already I have explained it in algo part. Its a simple c++ programming. I want to automate taking its choice by bat file

Comment: ok so you don't want an EXE file at all then

Comment: @barlop The "choice" command can make choices for interactive batch file. But my requirement is to automate an interactive command line c++ programming

Comment: @barlop Not that, already I have the exe. and I just want to run its options NOT manually, but using bat.

Comment: there is also set /p http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307512/create-a-batch-file-with-multiple-options   but anyhow.. if you want c++ then why did you tag it batch?

Comment: ok. What options/parameters does fruit.exe take?

Comment: @barlop There is no option there. Yes, actually, I want to automate whole thing of command promt by bat file, it will actually run on server. :)

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do but here is a simple bat that you might be able to amend to make it more what you want http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vmQLjWK4    <-- So run that bat file and study it a bit, it's very simple,, you'll understand it as you know some c++

Comment: @barlop Then can you please tell me one thing, is it possible by one single command ?

Comment: Well, I don't think you are that good at explaining what you want to do so I can't say for sure if what you want to do is posible in one command,  but assuming you have some programming skills, can you amend that batch file to do more what you want?

Comment: Do you have fruit.exe meat.exe e.t.c.?  And so your batch file is a menu that calls them?