# Batch file's IF statement is not working?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I did this just as an experiment out of interest, after some quick reads on tutorials online and SO questions.

This is the Batch file I created.

```
@ECHO OFF

:input
SET /P typeofc="To Connect input Y and to Disconnect input N (Y/N): "
IF /I "%typeofc%"=="Y" goto yes
IF /I "%typeofc%"=="N" goto no

:yes
rasdial whatevernetwork

:no
rasdial whatevernetwork /DISCONNECT
```

However, when I execute this, it runs both of the commands in `yes` and `no` regardless the condition given. Tried doing the `IF <condition> <command> ELSE <command>` too but then it simply exits after the input even if I add a `PAUSE` at the end of the script.

What have I done wrong in this?

P.S: I execute this on Windows 7 32-bit

Comment: there is nothing to stop the execution after `rasdial whatevernetwork`, so  the next line will be executed (and ignored, because it's a label), then the next line `rasdial whatevernetwork /DISCONNECT` will be executed. To stop execution, you can use `goto :eof` or `exit`. Your `if ... goto` statements themselves are executing fine at my computer. (doing both with `Y`, only the second one with `N`

Comment: If your input is any other than `Y` or `N` also both `ras`commands will be run.

Comment: Yes. You were absolutely correct. The issue was that I had not written anything to do after the executing the label. Adding them solved it. Plus like you said any input other than `Y` and `N` simply executed everything below. so I added the `IF` statement that checks the `N` into a different label, jumped into that if the statement for `Y` returned false and then called the `:input` again if the statement there returned false. Plus I found why my `ELSE` didn't work too. Turns out you have to put the command for true section within brackets. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: why don't use [choice](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command? [Create a batch file with multiple options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9307512/995714), http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_%28command%29

Comment: That's even more interesting. And simplifies the script too. Didn't know about `CHOICE` before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Stephan - `exit /b` is the direct equivalent of `goto :eof`. The plain `exit` command will kill the command session, which may not be desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
@echo off
:input
cls
ECHO.
SET /P typeofc="To Connect input Y and to Disconnect input N (Y/N): "
IF /I "%typeofc%"=="Y" goto yes
IF /I "%typeofc%"=="N" goto no
ECHO "%typeofc%" is not valid. Please try again.
pause
GOTO input

:yes
echo rasdial whatevernetwork
rasdial whatevernetwork
pause
exit /b

:no
echo rasdial whatevernetwork /DISCONNECT
rasdial whatevernetwork /DISCONNECT
pause
exit /b
```

Comment: Yes. This solved it. And helped me to have a better understanding on how it works as well.  Thanks Hackoo.